# What is the Difference between returning IModel<?> and <M> IModel<M>?

Tags: java, generics, wicket

There is a library/framework I use a lot that has some methods like this:

```
public IModel<?> getDefaultModel() { /* implementation here */ }
```

Using this method is fine, but sometimes I want to then call `container.getDefaultModel().getObject().foo()`. However, because `getDefaultModel()` returns an `IModel<?>` that means that `getObject()` returns an `Object`.

So I'm forced to use:

```
((Bar)container.getDefaultModel().getObject()).foo()
```

or

```
((IModel<Bar>)container.getDefaultModel()).getObject().foo()
```

But if the method had been specified like this:

```
    public <M> IModel<M> getDefaultModel() { /* implementation here */ }
```

Then I could use:  `container.<Bar>getDefaultModel().getObject().foo()`
Which I personally think is a much nicer/cleaner syntax.

The framework writers are very smart people, so I'm curious, other than the casting syntax, what differences are there in the two different definitions?

---

While we're on the subject, and please let me know if this should be a separate question.
Since the Generics code uses a compile time check instead of a runtime cast, would it generate slightly faster runtime code, then the explicit cast version?

Comment: This looks like Apache Wicket to me. Not, that it changes anything about the question of course.

Comment: Good eye, it is indeed Wicket. I was just trying to keep the question as generic (no pun intended) as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no other differences. The difference lies purely in the syntax. With `IModel<?>`, the casting has to be done explicitly (as you noted). However, by using generics, you tell the compiler to cast it to `Bar` when returning from the `getObject()` method, so you don't have to cast it yourself. Other than that, the exact same thing happens in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

For java versions 1.7 and earlier i guess, the compiler could not infer the type when you use a generic type in chained method calls (container.getDefaultModel().getObject()).foo()).So you have to cast it explicitly. But if you are using Java 8, I don't think you need to cast anymore. `container.getDefaultModel().getObject()).foo()`  will work.

Read this http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101 and this http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/25/a-lesser-known-java-8-feature-generalized-target-type-inference/

Comment: From how I understand it, this would allow leaving out the `<Bar>` in `container.<Bar>getDefaultModel().getObject().foo()` if `getDefaultModel()` were of the form `public <M> IModel<M> getDefaultModel() { /* implementation here */ }`. But it isn't.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But it will compile only for Java 8